# Learning resources to transerfer my MS SQL Server knowledge into MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm an experienced MS SQL Server developer 
But with my first MySQL project I got problems with very simple issues 

So can anyone suggest good resources helping me transfer my MS SQL Server knowledge into MySQL
I'm not looking for a complete reference guide for MySQL
I'm looking for something targeted for experienced SQL developers

**EDIT**: here are sample of issues I faced (thanks [Neil Butterworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/neil-butterworth))

1- Where to write my first "select * from", NOW I know that 
        - I've to [download MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads) which is NOT coming with IDE
 - I can pick up [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/download_form.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webyog.com%2Fdownloads%2FSQLyog805.exe) as MySQL IDE
2- How to execute multiple sql statements in the same query([done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763442/what-is-the-equivalent-of-go-in-mysql))
3- How to declare variables ([done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763718/whats-wrong-with-this-mysql-statement-declare-id-int))
4- How to write simple cursor (still trying)
5- How to add primary key to existing table by MySQL query not by IDE (still trying)
6- What is the different between [Wamp Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [MySQL + SQLyog] (still trying)

Comment: It would be a good idea to summarise the issues you have problems with in your question

Comment: There was a similar question with very usefull answers: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368858/hidden-features-of-mysql](http://)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably aren't going to be any guides that address your specific issues, so I'd just recommend reading through the excellent documentation on the MySQL website.  If you have a particular problem that's causing grief, and that isn't addressed in the docs, then ask about it here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good place to start:
[Migrating From MS SQL to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html)