# Why sql-script isn't executed?

Tags: sql, mysql, ddl, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE PERMISSIONS(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE(ID)
) 
CREATE TABLE ROLES(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   NAME VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I want to run this in MySql. When I try to execute separately each create-query everything works fine but they don't work together. I thought that separator was missed and tried to put semicolon after each query but MySql says that I have syntax mistake near ";" . Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the queries in the mysql console with a semi-colon after the each statement works. maybe you use an api (like php's mysql_query) which only supports one query at the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a semi-colon.

[What is the equivalent of 'go' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763442/what-is-the-equivalent-of-go-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySql instance running here and it's by no means my cup of tea but I believe you're supposed to separate your queries with ;.

```
CREATE TABLE PERMISSIONS(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE(ID)
) ;
CREATE TABLE ROLES(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   NAME VARCHAR(255)
)
```